# Need vertical text to align with left of banner starting from bottom

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I have some text that I would like to vertically align with my banner image.
I would like the text to start on the bottom left of the banner image.
I am using Drupal, so I had to add a text block that is right next to the banner image block.

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

But instead if looks like this:

[image]

Here is the website where the banner/text is being served from:

[Banner & Text Web Page](http://edigest.elaw.org/)

Here is the css I am using to cause the vertical text that should align to the left of the banner:

```
.vertical-text {
float: left;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin: left bottom 0;
```

}

Can anyone help me align the text correctly?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

test this :

```
.vertical-text {
  float: left;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom 0;
  margin-right:-30px; //or change it until be that you want 
  margin-bottom:-100px; 
}
```

**EDIT**

```
#header-image{
  position:relative;
  width:700px;
  height:300px;
  // ...
 }
.vertical-text {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:-20px;
   transform: rotate(-90deg);
   transform-origin: left bottom 0;
}


 <div id="header-image">
    <div class="vertical-text"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do is that after div  `content` create class for p tag and add below css

i have checked it see the screenshot
[image]

```
<div class="content">
    <p class="zeroo"">
<a href="/abouttheartist">About the Artist</a></p>
  </div>
```

css

```
.zeroo{
position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
left: -340px;
}
```